# Is there a luasocket library compatibile with lua 5.2.1?

Tags: windows, http, sockets, lua, luasocket

Just like the title says, I need a luasocket library for Windows compatible with Lua 5.2.1.

Comment: LuaSocket is compatible with 5.1

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9746939/3019030

Seems very thought out!

Answer (score 4):

`luasocket` has been ported to 5.2. see https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/tree/unstable

Comment: Too buggy. =/ Requires a lot of fiddling to even make it compile.